# How can I get the 'Sign Up' link in the header to disappear after the user logs in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZU3P.png)

I am developing my first RAILS application whilst using the Devise GEM for authentication.

I would like users who have Signed Up already and are subsequently Signed In to my application (to have the "Signed Up' link in the header *not* be made available to them).

Can someone kindly guide me as to how I can modify my attached syntax to provide this.

Thank you in advance of your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZU3P.png)

Comment: are you using devise for user auth?

Comment: Yes I am using devise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem for user authentication, you can verify if a user is signed in using the `user_signed_in?` helper method:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= button_to "SIGN OUT", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
<% else %>
    <%= button_to "SIGN IN", new_user_session_path, :method => "get" %>

<%end %>
```

- Here you are checking if the `user_signed_in?` return true and if so, you will show the sign out path to destroy a user's session.

From the link you provided (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZU3P.png) your problem is that you did not wrap the `<%= link_to "signup", new_user_session_path %>` into the conditional statement.
So to solve your problem you should do this:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
 <%= link_to "logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "signup", new_user_registration_path %>
  <%= link_to "signin", new_user_session_path %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Will the 'SIGN UP" path disappear when this syntax is implemented.

Comment: Yes, if the user is signed in and you wrap the sign up `link_to` tag within the `else` statement, then it will only show when a user isn't signed in

Comment: really appreciate your help. I will try this out. thank you.

Comment: No worries, if you have any user authentication question I suggest you go take a look at the documentation here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: This does not work. Your code makes ugly red writing appear on my application

Comment: Could you be more precise and maybe show the code in your question, can't help you without that... And yes, this code does work, this is how you toggle between a signup/signin link and a signout one. The formatting and styling is UP TO YOU. But this logic is correct!

Comment: When the user has put in their username and password credentials succesfully and Signed in/Logged in - I want the "Signup link" in the header to disappear. I do not want any other text prompts to appear on the screen.

Comment: Its not. I do not want the link displayed LOL. I want the "Signup" link on the header to disappear upon authentication of a login or signup.

Comment: If you take a good look at what you are doing you will notice that you have twice signup/login in your html. https://www.dropbox.com/s/n8rrf0mq9otjgm6/stack.png?dl=0. You need to enclose them into the conditional statement so that they don't display otherwise they will always appear... next time please put the code in your question, we prefer to see it there than to follow a link an view your code as a screenshot....

Comment: No it is not. My answer clearly shows you that you need to wrap your links into a conditional statement. From the picture you sent that is not what I see. Please review the basics of developing with Rails [HERE](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). Good luck!